# Ubuntu LTS or 21.04 for an AMD Ryzen 5?

Tags: kernel, hardware, cpu, lts, 21.04

I just bought a new laptop which has an AMD Ryzen 5 and I plan to give it Ubuntu. I'm more of a LTS guy, but I read on some blog that the new Linux kernel 5.11, which is boarded on Ubuntu 21.04, gives better support for AMD processors. What would you guys recommend me? Thanks right ahead!

Comment: If you look at https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle you will see that Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS will be getting the 5.11 kernel.  Which is scheduled for August.  So, this would be up to you.

Comment: The Ubuntu Desktop installer includes a "Try Ubuntu" environment specifically so you can test your own hardware risk-free, and judge which works better for yourself.